# When is it better to exclude outliers and calculate the mean of the data instead of using the median?

Tags: mean, outliers, skewness, median, trimmed-mean

I already searched on when to use the mean and median and I often see that median might be better than mean when the data is skewed, ordinal, include outliers, etc.. even tho, this might not be always the case.

Well, if the outliers are excluded when calculating the mean (trimmed mean), can this give a better sense of the centrality of the data? When is it better or makes a significant difference to use which? I just want to get more insight on when to use which. Can you please clarify with examples? Thank you.

Comment: What might be better depends very much on what the aim is...

Comment: When some values are definitely just random noise from a process that it is not of interest - e.g. you tried measuring deep sea light levels,  but accidentally switched on your sensors in your brightly lit laboratory - for most purposes that preservation may be useless.