# When is variance a better description of spread over IQR? What about mean over median for description of center?

Tags: variance, median

I was reading that IQR and median are a better representation of spread and center when there are outliers and when the distribution is skewed. When is variance a better measure of spread? What about mean a better measure of center than median?

Comment: "IQR and median are a better representation of spread and center when there are outliers and when the distribution is skewed" should be "IQR and median are a better representation of spread and center when there are outliers OR when the distribution is skewed." ===>"IQR and median are not a better representation of spread and center when there is no outlier and when the distribution is not skewed." ==>"Varaince and mean are a better representation of spread and center when there is no outlier and when the distribution is not skewed."

Comment: Maybe dup:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365935/when-is-it-better-to-exclude-outliers-and-calculate-the-mean-of-the-data-instead